# Android: I cannot upload HelloWorld to Acer BeTouch E110 - adb doesn't see it. Any thoughts?

Tags: android, adb, device

$ sudo platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached

I've just spent several hours googling and trying to get it worked

Ubuntu 10.10
USB debugging is turned on.

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 040: ID 0502:3212 Acer, Inc.

Played alot with /etc/udev/rules.d/*-android.rules, sudo service udev restart/reload, adb kill-server and sudo adb start-server...

Here are some of the settings I used for the rules file (one by one):

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{product}=="Android Phone", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3212", MODE="0666"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3212", MODE="0666"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3212", MODE="0666", ENV{ACL_MANAGE}="1"

Some info which might be useful:
$ dmesg|tail -5
[12888.236175] usb 1-8: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 42
[12888.389921] scsi41 : usb-storage 1-8:1.0
[12889.394601] scsi 41:0:0:0: Direct-Access Linux File-Stor Gadget 0322 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[12889.397545] sd 41:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[12889.411569] sd 41:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

$ ls -l /dev/sdb /dev/sg2
brw-rw-rw- 1 root disk 8, 16 2010-12-16 18:52 /dev/sdb
crw-rw-rw- 1 root disk 21, 2 2010-12-16 18:52 /dev/sg2

$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/043
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 42 2010-12-16 18:52 /dev/bus/usb/001/043

$ udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/sdb

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/host42/target42:0:0/42:0:0:0/block/sdb':
KERNEL=="sdb"
SUBSYSTEM=="block"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{range}=="16"
ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
ATTR{removable}=="1"
ATTR{ro}=="0"
ATTR{size}=="0"
ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
ATTR{capability}=="51"
ATTR{stat}==" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
ATTR{inflight}==" 0 0"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/host42/target42:0:0/42:0:0:0':
KERNELS=="42:0:0:0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
DRIVERS=="sd"
ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
ATTRS{type}=="0"
ATTRS{scsi_level}=="3"
ATTRS{vendor}=="Linux "
ATTRS{model}=="File-Stor Gadget"
ATTRS{rev}=="0322"
ATTRS{state}=="running"
ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x2e7"
ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x2e7"
ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x215"
ATTRS{modalias}=="scsi:t-0x00"
ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/host42/target42:0:0':
KERNELS=="target42:0:0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
DRIVERS==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/host42':
KERNELS=="host42"
SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
DRIVERS==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0':
KERNELS=="1-8:1.0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
ATTRS{modalias}=="usb:v0502p3212d0322dc00dsc00dp00 ic08isc06ip50"
ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="0"
ATTRS{interface}=="Mass Storage"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8':
KERNELS=="1-8"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{configuration}=="Self-powered"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="c0"
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="3100"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="3212"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0322"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{speed}=="480"
ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
ATTRS{devnum}=="43"
ATTRS{devpath}=="8"
ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 2.6.27-nxp with pnx67xx_ehci_udc"
ATTRS{product}=="File-backed Storage Gadget"
ATTRS{serial}=="3230204E6F76"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1':
KERNELS=="usb1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{configuration}==""
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
ATTRS{bMaxPower}==" 0mA"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="969"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0206"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{speed}=="480"
ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="8"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 2.6.35-23-generic ehci_hcd"
ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"
ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.7"
ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7':
KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.7"
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
DRIVERS=="ehci_hcd"
ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
ATTRS{device}=="0x265c"
ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1025"
ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x006a"
ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
ATTRS{irq}=="23"
ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
ATTRS{modalias}=="pci:v00008086d0000265Csv00001025 sd0000006Abc0Csc03i20"
ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
ATTRS{companion}==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
SUBSYSTEMS==""
DRIVERS==""

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different way to do it I've found after spending heaps of time.

1. Turn on USB debugging
2. Switch USB mode to sync
3. Connect your phone, it should be identified as a network interface (usbN)
4. Setup the interface as 192.168.1.2/24

Now you should be able to connect to the device:

$ platform-tools/adb connect 192.168.1.1
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.1.1:5555

$ platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached 
192.168.1.1:5555    device

However, it didn't help me because it turned out that I need root privileges on the device to be able to install applications through adb.

Comment: Now I push an apk file to the device and then install it by phone installer.

Answer (score -1):

Restart adb as root. Its not perfect but it will get you going. If you don`t want to run it as sudo all the time you are going to need someone with a long beard to help you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've done it before (sudo adb start-server as well as sudo adb devices) - no luck...